# How can i get IP address connections in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

Morning!

I have this message in my MariaDB container log:

```
2019-11-05  8:42:50 185 [Warning] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I don't know from where is being done this connections.. There is any way to get the IP Address from where those connections are being made?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, login into your MySQL/MariaDB console and enter the following command.

```
update mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where User='root';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

You can create log file :

Enter to MySQL/MariaDB server command-line tool

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Set the general log file path:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log_file='/var/log/mysql/mycustom.log';
```

Set the log output to file format:

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'FILE';
```

Enable the server general log:

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
```

Show the general log settings:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "general_log%";
```

Comment: But this grant is for give permissions to user root, right? My question is how to know which host o IP is doing this specific connections.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can create log file to see the requests being logged into the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The log is created correctly but i just see the connections with another user (correct connections) but i don't see root connectiones.. I executed the commands that you said me with no errors.. By other way, my docker log keep receiving the same message of root@localhost....

Comment: I tried to remove root password with: SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost=PASSWORD(''); and the messages has stopped in container log, and now i see in the log something like this: 191105 14:59:43   5668 Connect  root@localhost as anonymous on . What it's means?